# Installing a modified version of Android app

Tags: android-intent

I acquired some open source code for an Android app that I also installed from the Android Market.  I would like to make a second version that I can play with while still keeping the official one on my device.

I have tried changing the application name in @string/app_name and changed the launch configuration name in Properties->Run/Debug Settings.  It has an activity-alias in the manifest file and I changed that.  For good measure I also added android:label="@string/app_name" to intent-filter, both for the app and for the activity-alias.  I also went ahead and refactored the default activity to a different name.

I still get the following error:

Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!

If I uninstall the original app I can install / launch / run from Eclipse with no problem, but I really want to be able to have both versions available.  I don't mind changing names or whatever to make that happen.  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to do this by also changing the package name.  In Eclipse, right-click on the project, select Android Tools -> Rename Application Package.  I had to fix up the Manifest file because it got corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you have to rename the app package to a new one.
But be sure to modify AndroidManifest.xml in

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="your_new_package"`